# AJAX JSON Data Population on Button Click - Array Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to figure out how to select specific JSON objects when a line item meets a variable or variables that is passed on button click.  So far, I get it to work but it says [object],[object].  I believe this is because it is returned in an array.  What am I missing?

```
    var Type = "Champagne";

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $("#data-details").empty();
            $.get("working-data-file.json",{Type: Type},function(result){
                $.each(result.data, function(i, field){
                    $("#data-details").append(this.objects.Title);
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

The .JSON file looks like this:

```
{"objects": 
    [
        {
        "Type": "Champagne",
        "Sweetness": "Brut",
        "Producer": "Dom Perignon",
        "Vintage": "2006", 
        "Recommendation": "Classic",
        "Data": "12.29.2012",
        "Title": "The wine’s opulence – contained and succulent, round at heart – reveals itself in the mouth."
        },
        {
        "Type": "Cava",
        "Sweetness": "Brut-Nature",
        "Producer": "Canals Canals",
        "Vintage": "2014",
        "Recommendation": "Preferred",
        "Data": "12.29.2012",
        "Title": "2nd Cava."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: do you have problem in looping through `json` data?

Comment: I was just going over a tutorial that mentioned I would need to loop through the data.  To which I modified this slightly but just results in a blank.

Comment: did you get data properly?

Comment: `$.each(result.objects,function(k,v){//your code})` this will solve your problem just give it try

Comment: Does the k,v stand for key and value?

Comment: yes its `k` return index of object `v` whole object

Comment: did you get solution?

Comment: I did, I can get it to return text but not the actual array information and I think my selector of Type: Type doesn't work because it still returns two results.

Comment: now where you stuck?

Comment: Getting, close thanks for your help!  I am not sure what to put in my append(); if I put append("Return"); it appends 'Return' 7 times, as many items are in the array. I just need it to return a specific name like .Producer or .Title.  I think it would be something like this.Objects.Title

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132047/discussion-between-uzaif-and-ross-bethune).

Comment: it will  iterate based on result object  count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can loop through with jquery each.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('#button').click(function(e){
    $.each(data.objects, function( i, item) {
     $("#data-details").append('<p>' + item.Title + '</p>');
   });
 })
});


var data = {"objects": 
    [
        {
        "Type": "Champagne",
        "Sweetness": "Brut",
        "Producer": "Dom Perignon",
        "Vintage": "2006", 
        "Recommendation": "Classic",
        "Data": "12.29.2012",
        "Title": "The wine’s opulence – contained and succulent, round at heart – reveals itself in the mouth."
        },
        {
        "Type": "Cava",
        "Sweetness": "Brut-Nature",
        "Producer": "Canals Canals",
        "Vintage": "2014",
        "Recommendation": "Preferred",
        "Data": "12.29.2012",
        "Title": "2nd Cava."
        }
    ]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=button id="button" value="click me"/>

<div id="data-details"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```js
var result={"objects": 
    [
        {
        "Type": "Champagne",
        "Sweetness": "Brut",
        "Producer": "Dom Perignon",
        "Vintage": "2006", 
        "Recommendation": "Classic",
        "Data": "12.29.2012",
        "Title": "The wine’s opulence – contained and succulent, round at heart – reveals itself in the mouth."
        },
        {
        "Type": "Cava",
        "Sweetness": "Brut-Nature",
        "Producer": "Canals Canals",
        "Vintage": "2014",
        "Recommendation": "Preferred",
        "Data": "12.29.2012",
        "Title": "2nd Cava."
        }
    ]
}

Object.keys(result).forEach(key => {
  let value = result[key];
  console.log(value[0].Title);
})
```

[key]
})